# Determine if running on a console in illumos/solaris

Tags: c, console, solaris, x11

There is [a function](http://cgit.osdyson.org/xorg.git/tree/debian/local/xserver-wrapper.c#n154) used in Debian's X wrapper. This function determines whether X is running on a console (virtual terminal), it works on linux and freebsd.

What are ways to do the same on illumos/solaris?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `VT_GETSTATE` ioctl can be used to determine the active VT on Solaris 11.   See the [vt(7I) man page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29044/vt-7i.html#scrolltoc) for details.

Comment: Yeah, I used KDGETMODE. My problem was I did not understand how ioctl is used :-). The idea is simple: console ioctl only works with consoles.

Answer (score 0):

```
diff --git a/debian/local/xserver-wrapper.c b/debian/local/xserver-wrapper.c
index d4a6ab8..31e5343 100644
--- a/debian/local/xserver-wrapper.c
+++ b/debian/local/xserver-wrapper.c
@@ -116,6 +116,9 @@
 #define TTY_MAJOR_DEV 4
 #elif defined(__FreeBSD__) || defined(__FreeBSD_kernel__)
 #include <sys/consio.h>
+#elif defined(__sun__)
+#include <sys/kd.h>
+#include <sys/vt.h>
 #endif

 #define X_WRAPPER_CONFIG_FILE "/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config" 
@@ -171,6 +174,10 @@ onConsole()

   if (ioctl(0, VT_GETINDEX, &idx) != -1)
     return TRUE;
+#elif defined(__sun__)
+  int mode;
+  if (ioctl(0, KDGETMODE, &mode) != -1) /* mode = 0 (KD_TEXT) or 1 (KD_GRAPHICS) */
+    return TRUE;
 #else
 #warning This program needs porting to your kernel.
   (void) fprintf(stderr, "X: unable to determine if running on a console\n");
```